# Pay using the customer's saved payment method in Stripe Elements

Tags: stripe-payments

I've created a PaymentIntent that has the customer's payment_method specified.
When I create a payment form using Stripe Elements, I get the following result:
[stripe form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C94Kw.png)

But I want the card input form to be displayed as in the checkout session. Somehow like this:
[expected stripe form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlFTW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pre-fill the payment method of the Payment Element. But if you already have a PaymentMethod saved for the customer, then you don't need the Payment Element at all:

1. Create the PaymentIntent on the backend with `payment_method: pm_xxx` and `confirm: true`.
2. Then check the PaymentIntent status:

   - If it's `succeeded`, then there's nothing else to do.
   - If it's `requires_action`, then you need to confirm it on the frontend using [`stripe.confirmCardPayment()`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-attached).